# Font-Awesome How to get fonts to scale?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I'm trying desperately to get my magnifying glass font to render it larger. The code below works fine in firefox but not in Chrome or IE9.

What am I missing?

```
.icon-larger
{
   font-size:50px;
}

<div class="search-icon"><i class="icon-search icon-larger"></i></div>
```

thanks!

Comment: Could you please make a reproducible test-case?

Answer (score 16):

Take a look at this [page](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/) and see the examples that scale icons size.

You can scale up to 5 times it's size.

Example:

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i> fa-lg
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-2x"></i> fa-2x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x"></i> fa-3x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-4x"></i> fa-4x
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-5x"></i> fa-5x
```

Answer (score 11):

The Font Awesome icon is hooked to the :after pseudo element, so your CSS would need to be

```
.icon-larger:before 
{
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

I have created a reference page of all the CSS content values for Font Awesome, along with a CSS snippet which shows how to use the icons with any element: http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:block` or `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I had the same issue and it appeared I forgot to include the Font Awesome css e.g: `<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

You will still see the icon, but it will not scale when this is missing.